# Are vintage devices compatible with iCloud?

Tags: icloud

I would like to know if Notes, Calendar, iCloud Drive, Keychain, Mail and other native apps are compatible with vintage and obsolete products.

[Apple KB - Vintage and obsolete products](https://support.apple.com/HT201624)

Comment: This seems quite broad but Allan has the correct answer, Apple services work based on a matrix of availability, security (some mandate TFA), and software version. Indirectly, hardware affects OS but it’s not the direct yes/no vote.

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.9, which I believe is the earliest with iCloud support. All iCloud functionality still works save "Documents & Data" (the predecessor to iCloud Drive), which can be enabled but will not actually sync to other machines (including 10.9 machines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notes, iCloud, etc. are not determinant on the hardware, but what version of macOS you're using.

Comment: You are right Allan. Here is think for the recommended system requirements and minimum system requirements for iCloud. Seems Apple is quite generous giving long term support for the native apps https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230